# xsl match or condition

Tags: xslt, match

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<bases>
<marker>
       <name>whatever</name>
       <city>Svetly</city>
       <country>Kaliningrad</country>
</marker>
<marker>
       <name>whatever</nane>
       <city>Boston</city>
       <country>US</country>
</marker>
<marker>
       <name>whatever</nane>
       <city>Moscow</city>
       <country>Russia</country>
</marker>
</bases>
```

This XSL allows me to do a selective copy - in this case where the country equals Russia.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!-- Remove all marker elements where country not 'Russia' -->
  <xsl:template match="marker[not(country='Russia')]"/>
  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd like to implement an OR condition, such as where country equals Russia OR Kaliningrad but I can't figure out the syntax. This doesn't work:

<xsl:template match="marker[not(country='Russia|Kaliningrad')]"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3: `<xsl:template match="marker[not(country=('Russia', 'Kaliningrad'))]"/>`. In XSLT 1: `<xsl:template match="marker[not(country='Russia' or country = 'Kaliningrad')]"/>`